# Setting up a text notification when a large file transfer is complete

Tags: files, notification

I often have to copy 100-200 GB of files from one drive to another. I use my Ubuntu desktop, which is downstairs, to do this. However, I usually work upstairs. I would like to somehow get a notification on my Android phone, e.g. via text, that my file transfer has completed. Is there anyway to do this easily? Or a way to do this not easily? Google isn't turning up much!